# Assert LinkedHashMap element in jUnit test

Tags: java, unit-testing, validation, junit

So I have some test, maybe the given side of that test is not so important to catch the point of my confusion. I wrote

```
List<LinkedHashMap> failedEvents = ...
//...
assertEquals(failedEvents.size(),1 );
assertTrue(failedEvents.stream().allMatch(x -> x.get("eventId").equals("EVENT3")));
```

and in the result my code review said I should avoid stream on single element. But I think is clear and readable to show that all elements pass specific matching rule.
Also I though about assertThat, but I ended with much bigger and more complicated piece of code.

Comment: Your title should explain what the code does, not what your question asks.

Comment: so, now it's correct ?

Comment: The test should not require any of the functional code.  The subject under test should provide the expected value.  Also the values in your assertions are transposed, the expected value should be first and the actual value second.  http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One cannot say anything against

```
assertEquals(failedEvents.size(), 1);
assertEquals(failedEvents.get(0).get("eventId"), "EVENT3");
```

It is even shorter and more clear.

However your argument of an **invariant** on the entire collection is valid, though
you should have said so. Better would be to make a reusable assertion:

```
assertEquals(failedEvents.size(), 1);
assertTrue(failedEventsHaveId(failedEvents, "EVENT3"));

/**
 * Invariant on the failedEvent: the eventId remaining one.
 */
private static boolean failedEventsHaveId(..., String eventId) {
    return ...;
}
```

If **not** reusable, then the code is unnecessarily "nice."